# Maven install:? - how to create a release candidate?

Tags: maven

Is it possible to create a release candidate from my current maven project without changing the version number in the pom.xml?

I just want to build a new maven artifact form my project with a specific version number.

For example: my current pom.xml has the version '0.0.1'. I have called `mvn install` to create the artifact in my local repository. Now I would like to create a second artifact with the version '0.0.1-RC1'

Is this possible from the mvn command line without changing the version number in my pom.xml?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would advice against your suggestion of *not* changing the version number. One of the Maven's benefits is to keep your releases in sequence, i.e. after you have made your '0.0.1-RC1' candidate you will continue to work on the '0.0.1-RC2-SNAPSHOT' version (which may result in a '0.0.1-RELEASE').

That said, you don't have to change the version number manually. The [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/index.html) offers great help with this with commands such as `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`. Also read the Maven build versions in the [Maven reference manual](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html). You may also find the discussion about [Maven version scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048437/what-version-numbering-scheme-to-use) interesting.

Comment: thanks. mvan release helps me to get the things done. I use just the release:prepare and release:clean goal to tag the last version and start with a new developer version. I did no use the release:perform goal as I have no official mvn repository.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it you have two options:

1. Embrace the [release plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/index.html). It's been designed to address this problem.
2. Use the [versions plug-in](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and issue your own source code control commands.

Comment: It isn't that much of a pain, just use the versions plugin.

Comment: Agreed. Removed the rant stuff and focused on solution