# Software versioning standards

Tags: standards, versioning

Are there any software versioning standards? Or i can change version of my product, when i have made some changes to it?

Is there any percentage in changes, by which i can say, what version this product will have?

Comment: See also: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-version-typically-represent-i-e-v1-9-0-1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615227/how-to-do-version-numbers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889615/version-numbering-basics

Comment: Especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615227/how-to-do-version-numbers

Comment: For end-user software you can practically run wild and let PR handle the version numbers. For libraries you should go a more engineering-like route ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No rules. You decide.

There seems to be a common agreement:

- You increment the version number when you make significant changes or the amount of service packs and updates makes the application noticeably advanced over the original version.
- The smaller a change is, the smaller the increment in subversion numbers. Bug fix -> behavior change -> new feature -> service pack for lots of features -> some big change or a new module.

Answer (score 12):

Some people have proposed software version number conventions. Here are two:

- [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)
- [Apache APR Version Numbering Concepts](http://apr.apache.org/versioning.html)