# Alternative way of using Antd Table Columns and ColumnGroups

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

According to [Ant Design's Column grouping demo](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/demo/grouping-columns.md), [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) tables are usually just called like the following - assuming you have pre-filled `columns` and `data` appropriately:

```js
<Table 
   columns={columns} 
   dataSource={data} 
   // ... other parameters
/>
```

However, I stumbled upon code which uses deconstruction (`const { Column, ColumnGroup } = Table;`) and inheritance (e.g. `class MyTable extends Table<Interfaces.myTable>`) to allow a code like the following within the `return()` function of the `render()` part of a custom component

```
<div>
  <div className="myTable">
    <MyTable dataSource={myData}
             locale={{ emptyText: 'No data found'}}>
      <ColumnGroup title="Headline 1">
         <MyColumn title="Col 1.1" 
                   dataIndex="iName"
                   key="kName"
         />
      </ColumnGroup>
</MyTable>
```

The problem is now that this does now (after update from Antd 2.10.0 to 3.23.3) no longer work:

> Error TS2459 (TS) Type 'ComponentClass, "loading" | "footer" | "style" | "title" | "scroll" | "size" | "children" | "className" | "prefixCls" | "locale" | "getPopupContainer" | "onChange" | "dataSource" | ... 27 more ... | "sortDirections">, any>' has no property 'ColumnGroup' and no string index signature

I understand that this mainly because `node_modules\antd\lib\table\Table.d.ts` looks now different, and does not longer contain the `ColumnGroup` property. **What alternatives do I have now, if I do not want to rewrite literally thousand lines of code?**

Comment: @DennisVash The issue is that without v3.x.x I am missing essential features I need, so I guess I have to heavily rewrite the code and get rid of the inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Moving a major version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-version-typically-represent-i-e-v1-9-0-1) considered as *breaking changes*, therefore in your case you might want to stay in your current version `2.x.x` or re-implement components logics with the new version.

---

About [inheritance with React](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html),
React has a powerful composition model, its recommended to use composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components.

If you still [think about Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance):

> At **Facebook**, we use React in thousands of components, **and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies**.
>
> Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to customize a component’s look and behavior in an explicit and safe way. Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including primitive values, React elements, or functions.
>
> If you want to reuse non-UI functionality between components, we suggest extracting it into a separate JavaScript module. The components may import it and use that function, object, or a class, without extending it.

When you getting to a situation that inheritance is un-avoidable, try asking a senior React developer, you might just missing something, in any case you can always use [references](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs) and use composition on them.

Comment: I just learned the reason why we are using inheritance (in a somewhat mild form, if you may say so): I am told that it is a workaround to fix typescript errors occurring if the corresponding library is not taking care about using correct types itself.