# How can I AutoIncrement the assembly (build) number in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I AutoIncrement the assembly (build) number in Visual Studio?

#### Duplicate:

[/questions/650/automatically-update-version-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650/)

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a wildcard in the [AssemblyVersionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute.aspx):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

This will cause build to be equal to the number of days since January 1, 2000 local time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want from [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11160/Increment-Build-Number-in-VS-NET). Otherwise, you can do it from the property of the project by using the *.

Answer (score 1):

I use http://code.mattgriffith.net/UpdateVersion/ in a batch file as a pre-build step with calls to interact with our revision control system.

Answer (score 0):

Setting it as such should do so:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*.*")]
```

Comment: The `*.*` solution doesn't work. It uses "time of day" numbers which means generated files won't install from a .msi unless generated at a later time on any subsequent day. Make one late at night, and you're stuck. Can't seem to find a link for this, but I do recall using it was very painful.