# How to let visual studio setup project override all dlls - or how to let visual studio increase the version number with every build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, .net-assembly, assemblyversions

i am using the VS2010 Installer project to deploy my application. I can set the RemovePreviousVersions property to True and the installer will override every assembly with changed Version number. Problem is, we have around 30 projects, so it is practically impossible to increase all versions by hand. If i set

`[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]`

in the AssemblyInfo.cs VS properly generates the number which i can see if i check

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`

However, the installer does not reflect this...

So what i want to do is to either force the installer to override ALL assemblies no matter what version number, or i want to force the installer to uninstall the previous version beforehand, or i want visual studio to increase the version number with every build so that the setup project notices it.

As allways it seems to me like the simplest thing in the world but i can't figure how.

Answer (score 0):

There are several addins to visual studio which can increment build number automatically, eg. this:

http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/

Also take a look at this article : [How to have an auto incrementing version number (Visual Studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio)

Comment: your second link points me to using auto generated version numbers which on the one hand work fine, but on the other hand the setup project doesn't seem to like them. In other words, it seems to ignore auto gernated version numbers.

I had a look to other visual studio addins, but i am not really willing to install jet another beta to my development environment. I feel that there should be another solution.

Comment: check these links you may get your answer there  1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio/826850#826850     2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio