# Auto-Include Version # in Label

Tags: c#, version, auto-update

I am currently including the version number of my publish/release in a label on my application, but have been unable to figure out how to add it so that it auto-updates for every publish.  Currently, I am just using a simple text:

```
//VERSION LABEL
string version = "1.0.0.15 - BETA";
versionLabel.Text = "v" + version;
```

Is there a way to auto-update the version with each publish?

Comment: Just reading more carefully, I think this is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using the assembly version? Depending if you let it auto-uprev, this could save you some time.

```
var appVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
versionLabel.Text = String.Format("v{0}", appVersion);
```

This would be based on the `AssemblyInfo`'s version.

To elaborate on what I mean, if you look at `AssemblyInfo.cs`, you'll see something like the following:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

That's essentially saying that if you make it `1.0.*` or `1.0.0.*` that VS will assign a revision or build and revision, respectfully, for you with every compilation.

Comment: Just note that you need to import `System.Reflection`.

Comment: Say you had `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*.*")]` VS will auto-increment the build and revision for you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio

Comment: Basically, if you even tried to add an `About Box` you can see this code used to get the version to be displayed in it.

Comment: @Jeagr: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No....but I am not familiar with adding in things like [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*.*")]... somewhat of a nub.

Comment: @Jeagr: Shouldn't have to add it. within visual studio, under your project, is a Properties node (above References node). inside is `AssemblyInfo.cs` which is where that line is. Make the last or last two values `*` and the version will change with each build.

Comment: ok..getting this:  Error 1 Error emitting 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute -- 'The version specified '1.0.*.*' is invalid' I:\___VS Projects\Keyworqs WPF\test1\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs 35 12 KeyworqsWPF

Comment: Figured it out...it was a syntax error.  This worked:  [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]