# When will be the AssemblyVersion incremented?

Tags: c#, .net

Propably a stupid question but here it goes.

I have a blank console application and I added to the AssemlyInfo.cs file this line of code.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

I'm wondering at what point gets the number incremented ?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of: [How to have an auto incrementing version number (Visual Studio)?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/826850/952310)

Answer (score 0):

It will be updated every day / build.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A version number such as `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]` specifies
>   1 as the major version, 2 as the minor version, and accepts the
>   default build and revision numbers. A version number such as
>   `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")]` specifies 1 as the major
>   version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts
>   the default revision number. **The default build number increments
>   daily. The default revision number is random.**

**Edit**: As of Framework 4.5, the revision number is no longer random; it is the number of seconds since midnight, divided by 2.

Comment: Like every time I build my project ? I did that couple of times and it is still 1.0.0.0

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't happen automatically out of the box.

Comment: @user49126 Are you checking the Product Version, or File Version on your built assembly?

Comment: Both values are 1.0.0.0

Comment: If you specify AssemblyFileVersion, it overrides AssemblyVersion. Remove the entry for AssemblyFileVersion and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Joel, this was the problem. Add it as an answer and I will accept it.