# Visual Studio web deploy - simple way to include build info?

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET site that I am deploying to Azure Websites. I have a production and staging environment there and it is easy to get lost which is which. During the web deploy ("Publish") from Visual Studio, is there some simple way to deploy some kind of build info that I could display either via the site itself or through the Azure Portal?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. where exactly do you want to expose that build info? In the website's UI? or in Portal UI? Portal already tells whether you are on a non-production slot. the siteName would be YourSiteName(YourSlotName).

Comment: Say that I fix some bug on a site but visually don't change anything. I deploy that to the staging slot and then forget whether I swapped with production or not. At this point, I need a way to tell which site is which version. If the Portal showed information like "last deployed time", I would just inspect these properties but as far as I can see, the Portal doesn't show any such info about the given slot. So I'm seeking an alternative - like generating some version.txt file at build time and visiting that in the browser or something like that. The simpler, the better.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a version number to your assembly by adding this line to `AssemblyInfo.cs` file

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

[more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio)

you can then expose it in your site however you want, maybe a hidden tag, some sort of debug info page, or write it to a file on Application_Start that you can look at later

for example in `global.asax` you can have

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("version.txt")
    {
        var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        writer.WriteLine(version);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating a text file with current date as a post-build step was the easiest solution I found.