# bat file to modify web.config setting

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a web application created in Visual Studio 2013. I have this appSetting in my Web.Config file:

```
<add key="cloudVersion" value="@@NEW@@"/>
```

After I publish the application, I run a bat file that copies the published directory, appends today's date to the directory name, compresses the updated directory, and uploads it to Google drive so the rest of my team can access it.

I am attempting to use the same bat file to modify the *cloudVersion* setting so we can see when it was published from within the application. I have this code:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=@@NEW@@"
set "replace=%yy%%mm%%dd%"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%""C:\original files\Web.config""%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%""C:\Publish Folder\CLOUD"%yy%.%mm%.%dd%"\Web.Config""%"
type "%""C:\Publish Folder\CLOUD"%yy%.%mm%.%dd%"\Web.Config""%"
```

It correctly copies the Web.Config file and replaces the *cloudVersion* variable value. However, the whole file now has each line numbered like this:

```
23:  </system.web.extensions>
24:  <appSettings>
25:    <add key="cloudVersion" value="20140818"/>
```

How do I use the bat to update the value, but not get numbered lines that I have to later delete?

Comment: `/n ` explicitly asks for line numbers, remove it.

Comment: @AlexK. I figured it would be easy, this is just my first experience with bat files. That worked, thanks! If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is looking, here is what I did:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=@@NEW@@"
set "replace=%yy%%mm%%dd%"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%""C:\original files\Web.config""%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%""C:\Publish Folder\CLOUD"%yy%.%mm%.%dd%"\Web.Config""%"
type "%""C:\Publish Folder\CLOUD"%yy%.%mm%.%dd%"\Web.Config""%"
```

Comment: I have tried this but i got empty file only instead of replacing. Did you aware of this?

Comment: It worked well for me. You just have to make sure you have all the correct settings and values.