# AssemblyInfo build number not updated

Tags: c#, versioning, assemblyinfo, assemblyversions, assemblyversionattribute

I have the following code in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I'm trying to make sure the `Build Number` changes each time I build/rebuild my project. But, in that case it doesn't. Only the `Revision` changes if I build it on different days.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is the File Version that is not changing?

The third number (out of 4) is the number of days since 2000. This will not change with each build, only with each passing day.

Change it to be:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable. So can I make sure the second number (out of 4) is updated with each build?

Comment: If you use 1.0.*, then the * will be the number that increments.

Comment: I see. Ok. Thanks. Actually I ended up using 'MinorRevision' variable instead.

Comment: However, you won't see this if you have both entries in AssemblyInfo.cs.

Comment: This is only valid for AssemblyFile. It will not work with AssemblyFileVersion.

Answer (score 3):

Just comment this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]    
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

If you need to change AssemblyFileVersion, you will have to do it manually..

Or, you can use T4 templating mechanism, as described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/827209/2748199)

Answer (score 2):

You need to comment out the

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) says:

> You can specify all the values or you can accept the default build
>   number, revision number, or both by using an asterisk (*). For
>   example, [assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")] indicates 2 as the
>   major version, 3 as the minor version, 25 as the build number, and 1
>   as the revision number. A version number such as
>   [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")] specifies 1 as the major version,
>   2 as the minor version, and accepts the default build and revision
>   numbers. A version number such as
>   [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")] specifies 1 as the major
>   version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts
>   the default revision number. The default build number increments
>   daily. The default revision number is the number of seconds since
>   midnight local time (without taking into account time zone adjustments
>   for daylight saving time), divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out 
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")] 
and leave only 
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

Comment: Tried...It doesn't work, I keep staying on the same build number.