# how to get publish version?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, desktop-application

I would like to show the publish version of my desktop application. I am trying to do it with this code:

```
_appVersion.Content = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

The problem is that I am not getting exactly the publish version I have in my project properties. Below is a screenshot of it:

[image]

But I am getting `3.0.0.12546`. Does someone know where is the problem?

Comment: are you checking in debug mode?

Comment: Nop, in release mode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was also having this issue and found that the version number set in `AssemblyInfo.cs` was interfering with the one set in `Properties`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I usually comment those lines out of `AssemblyInfo` and replace them with

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Check whether these values have been hard-coded into your `AssemblyInfo` file.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio) for an interesting discussion on automatic versioning. When checking `AssemblyInfo.cs`, make sure your auto-increment (`*` - if you are using it) only targets `AssemblyVersion` and not `AssemblyFileVersion`.

---

When debugging the program, you could check the properties of the assembly in

```
\bin\Release\app.publish
```

Under the `Details` tab, check the version number. Does this match up with any of the settings you specified in VS?

Comment: Perfect, your solution works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

> We can create one property which will return the Version information
>   as mention below and we can use that property.

```
public string VersionLabel
{
    get
    {
        if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
        {
            Version ver = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
            return string.Format("Product Name: {4}, Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", ver.Major, ver.Minor, ver.Build, ver.Revision, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);
        }
        else
        {
            var ver = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
            return string.Format("Product Name: {4}, Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", ver.Major, ver.Minor, ver.Build, ver.Revision, Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so i got this to work by placing it in the Main.CS and when i called it to a string i received 1.0.7379.32346 but my version is 20.03.8.3.  why am i getting the wrong version number? thanks Dave

Comment: i just installed the software to my laptop (Deploy) and i got the correct version number to display in the Main header text.  thanks for a great solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

will get you the assembly version that exist in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, to get the publish version that you set in the publish dialog, you should use

```
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
```

But notice that you have to add reference to System.Deployment, and it will work only after you publish your application by right click on the project file and click publish, everytime you publish, it will increment the Revision.

If you tried to call the above line in debug mode it will not work and will throw an exception, so you can use the following code:

```
try
{
    return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
}
```

Comment: Note that the second way works and shows the publish version when the app is published, but it will throw an error when launching the app directly from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Using C# 6.0 with Lambda expression

```
private string GetVersion => ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed 
    ? $"Version: {ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion}" 
    : $"Version: {Application.ProductVersion}";
```