# How to display updated version Number Automatically in Windows form Application c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have to display build version automatically without entering manually in windows form application, I have tried something like **[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]**
 in **assemblyInfo.cs** but its show like below,

**{1.0.7145.41554}** its looks awkward

I want show something like this **[1.0.0.13]** after published, but it always takes **[1.0.0.1]**

see the below image I want to show that version in view page actually
[image]

This is how I'm getting version; but it is returning [1.0.0.1]

```
 //Get Version of the currently executing Assembly
 var anm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
 ExistingVersion = String.Format("{0}", anm);
 EMajor = anm.Major;
 EMinor = anm.Minor;
 EBuildNo = anm.Build;
 ERevisionNo = anm.Revision;

 lblVersionv.Text = String.Format("Current Version : {0}", anm);
```

How I can do that?

Comment: that's what i want to show in display. my current version is 10.0.0.13 now. if i build one more time it would become 10.0.0.14 this version i need to displayin view page

Comment: I didn't set that it will take versions automatically for every publish.

Comment: Oops, it was written by mistake..its 1.0.0.13

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get publish version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721887/how-to-get-publish-version)

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39722554/1744164) from the duplicate

Comment: Yes thanks i got it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit convoluted but you can reach this info from your own code and then decide to display it how you like.

First step is the most critical, you need to get a Type from one of your own classes.
You can use your main form class for example

```
Type myApp = Type.GetType("your-full-qualified-class-name-here");
```

So suppose your namespace is "MyApplication" and your main form class is named "MyStartupForm" then you should replace the string above with "MyApplication.MyStartupForm" (be precise with upper/lowercase letters)

Now with the type you could get the the [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8) information with

```
Version v = myApp.Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

And finally the version variable will have all the info you need.
(Look at the property Build, Version, Revision, MinorRevision, MajorRevision)

Note also that the override for the ToString method will return to you a single string with all the information required

Comment: but this also will give version right?System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version

Comment: Yes, it is the same but shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by adding below code

```
 if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
  {
     lblVersionv.Text = string.Format("Version : {0}",ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString(4));
  }
```