# Build number in C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

In the custom process in our company we don't always deploy the small applications but instead we simply take the .exe file from debug.

Is there any way to keep a revision to this small executables?

Like an autoincrement that grows each time we compile it?

Could this be handled by a "prebuild" script in Visual Studio? - this would be ideal because it would work in both c# and vb.net.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio

Comment: exactly what I needed!  didn't knew how to google it, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this in case somebody reaches here:

there is a AssemblyInfo.vb file in the project containing

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```

replace it with

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")>
'<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>
```