# How to have an auto incrementing build version number (KDevelop)?

Tags: c++, linux, version, open-source, kdevelop

#### How to have an auto incrementing build version number in KDevelop?

I would like to set up a semi-automatic versioning for my local [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) projects in [kdevelop](/questions/tagged/kdevelop).

Something like:

```
int MajorVersion = 1;  // this manual 
int MinorVersion = 2;  // this manual
int Revision = 42;     // this automatically increased each time I compile
```

When I compile, it would auto-increment just the `Revision` field.

**Is this feature hidden somewhere in the settings and are those value maybe accessible from the system (mainly Linux, but all in general) or have they to be user implemented?**

Note that I'm searching for solution inside [kdevelop](/questions/tagged/kdevelop), or in case not yet allowed for a simple method usable from commandline compiling and then importable in  KDevelop.
I'm not searching solution for VisualStudio, as many answers offer from some similar questions <sup>[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio)],[[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356543/3569208)]...</sup>.

Comment: That's not a question for the IDE, that's a question for the build system in use. Which build system are you using?

Comment: @kfunk `cmake`. It seems kdevelop with c++ uses by default CMake... BTW I remember many years ago  that with Visual Studio this  was a feature integrated in the IDE (at the time of VB6, even if I cannot recall if was self-updating). Then it was possible to rescue those information in the executable file (right click, information)... so I was thinking that nowadays it was possible to find a similar feature in kdevelop too. Is there any standard in this direction?

Answer (score 4):

This has little to do with IDE you are using. It is rather buildsystem thing. If you are using CMake, I imagine something like this:

```
if(NOT BUILD_REVISION)
  set(BUILD_REVISION 0 CACHE STRING "")
else()
  math(EXPR BUILD_REVISION "${BUILD_REVISION} + 1")
endif()

add_definitions(-DBUILD_REVISION=${BUILD_REVISION})
```

And then in the code

```
int Revision = BUILD_REVISION;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will try to use with Kdevelop.

Comment: Note: This will recompile all your code whenever BUILD_REVISION changes -- better use a dedicated file (let's call it version.h) which contains the version string. See this how to: http://brianmilco.blogspot.de/2012/11/cmake-automatically-use-git-tags-as.html -- just include version.h where you need it then