# Custom auto increment assembly version

Tags: c#

How do I auto increment assembly version in my `Assembly.cs` file so that it is a custom increment like 1.4.001 and then each build after is 1.4.002 and so on.

Currently if I use

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.*")]
```

it returns `1.4.6865.30445`

Comment: Would this incremented version only apply to your machine? i.e. if you build on yours you'll get `1.4.003`, and then if I clone the code and build on my laptop I'll get `1.4.001`?

Comment: The only way that I know how to do this is to create an application (or powershell script) that can parse the Assembly.cs file and run that as part of the pre-build step. There is nothing built-into VS that does that. If you are using Team Services Source Control I think there is some settings that can adjust it though.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio