# AssemblyVersion using * fails with error "wildcards, which are not compatible with determinism?"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I can't use `*` in assembly version; when I do I get the following compilation error:

> The specified version string contains wildcards, which are not
> compatible with determinism. Either remove wildcards from the version
> string, or disable determinism for this compilation

[image: SCRAssembly]

Comment: Specific to .NETCore projects, /deterministic compile option.  You'd have to edit the .csproj file by hand to turn it off.  Do beware that the version is considerably worse that non-deterministic, as written the revision number will be the time of day.  So version numbers can go backwards or repeat, you might as well not use them at all.

Comment: Always post error message (and code) as text, not as images.

Comment: @HansPassant The default version is a combination of date and time of day, so unless there's a problem with the space-time continuum, the default build number and revision will always increase.  (I find it occasionally useful for determining when something was built).

Comment: You're talking about "1.0.*", that's not what they used.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I guess you were able to use it earlier and can't anymore.

Reason - There have been some changes to Visual Studio as the new project files now default to 'True' for 'Deterministic' attribute.

Solution - as Hans Passant says, edit project file by hand. Cons to doing it, also as he says.

Specifically, edit `.csproj` to `<Deterministic>false</Deterministic>`.

Source - https://marinovdh.wordpress.com/2018/10/22/68/

Comment: This does not resolve the issue on my VS2022 (17.6.2). Still getting that error stating that the specified version does not conform to the recommended format.

Answer (score 112):

Add `<Deterministic>` tag with `false` value and use `*` for the 3'rd part of `AssemblyVersion` inside `<PropertyGroup>` in **.csproj** file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

"Deterministic" means something like - the compiler will use the same versions of the files if no changes have happened resulting in faster builds.

It is the `AssemblyVersion` (not `AssemblyFileVersion`) that you should use a wildcard in. If you provide `AssemblyVersion` with wildcard, just don't include `AssemblyFileVersion` at all.

---

Note also: There are two forms. One where the asterisk wildcard is in the third position (`x.y.*`) and one where it is in the fourth position (`x.y.z.*`).

`x.y.*` auto-generates the BUILD and REVISION numbers. BUILD is the "number of days since 1st January 2000" thus it only changes once each day. and REVISION is "half the number of seconds since 00:00".

Today, for example, an `AssemblyVersion` of `'1.0.*'` will generate a specific `'7472'`, e.g. `'1.0.7472.20737'`. The 5-digit final number will be different every build, at least if changes.

This may be better than `1.0.0.*` for support as it indicates age (`.7300` would be almost 6 months old). The example, `1.0.7472.20737`, means "this assembly was built on 2020-06-16 at 11:31:14".

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for VS Pro 2019.  Just creates a ref folder with a bad exe in it.

Answer (score 4):

VS2019 can auto-create an `.editorconfig` file putting severity as 'suggest', which content is like this:

```
[*.cs]

    # CS7035: The specified version string does not conform to the recommended format - major.minor.build.revision
    dotnet_diagnostic.CS7035.severity = suggestion
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found this cool workaround for .Net Core projects that sheds lights on @Hans comment.

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <VersionSuffix>1.$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(yyMM)).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(ddhh)).$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(mmss))</VersionSuffix>
        <AssemblyVersion Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' == '' ">1.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
        <AssemblyVersion Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' != '' ">$(VersionSuffix)</AssemblyVersion>
        <Version Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' == '' ">1.0.0.1</Version>
        <Version Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' != '' ">$(VersionSuffix)</Version>
        <!--Deterministic tells the compiler to use the same versions of the files if no changes have happened resulting in faster builds-->
        <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
```

REF: https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/net-core-standard-auto-incrementing-versioning/