# Why IDEs (Rider & Visual Studio) don't increment Assembly version for '*' char according official documentation? How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rider

Windows 10 x64. Visual Studio 2019 v16.6.1. Rider 2020.1.3.

Microsoft [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?view=netcore-3.1):

> You can specify all the values or you can accept the default build
>   number, revision number, or both by using an asterisk (*). For
>   example, `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")]` indicates 2 as the
>   major version, 3 as the minor version, 25 as the build number, and 1
>   as the revision number. A version number such as
>   `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]` specifies 1 as the major version,
>   2 as the minor version, and accepts the default build and revision
>   numbers. A version number such as
>   `[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")]` specifies 1 as the major
>   version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts
>   the default revision number. **The default build number increments
>   daily. The default revision number is the number of seconds since
>   midnight local time (without taking into account time zone adjustments
>   for daylight saving time), divided by 2**.

I edited version info in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

But if I rebuild my project by Rider IDE and check assembly version I see unexpected result:

[image]

If I try to do the same in Visual Studio 2019 v16.6.1 then I get compilation error even:

[image]

If I set `Deterministic` to `false` according [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782085/visual-studio-assemblyversion-with-dont-work) then compilation error doesn't happen but I get the same result:

[image]

Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: If that's the way to say "you shouldn't use it any more", I won't be surprised.

Comment: @LexLi but why they writes info about '*' in the comments of AssemblyInfo.cs still?

Comment: Keep in mind documentation can easily go out-of-date. The comments have been there since .NET Framework 1.0 and probably no one really cares about whether they work or not today. BTW, SDK style projects no longer have that part, so the future is clear.

Comment: Apparently you need to [remove the `AssemblyFileVersion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356694/11683) for asterisks in `AssemblyVersion` to work. `AssemblyFileVersion` doesn't support asterisks anyway.

Comment: @GSerg you are right! Thank you!