# Generation of unique ID for each build / compilation other than build number

Tags: c#

Is there any way to generate some unique identifier for each compilation / build  which I can use as constant in other places of application other than build number?

Comment: Why do you need this? Just asking!

Comment: Some thought: You can write a pre-build action to update some custom attribute (like those attributes in AssemblyInfo.cs), using the Ticks value of the current time stamp.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the build number? The parts of the build number can be set to be some kind of timestamp, which will be unique for you as long as you don't compile two builds at the same time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826777/how-to-have-an-auto-incrementing-version-number-visual-studio

Comment: Basically we wanted to generate some id which we will later append with cookie names so that web applications can reside on single IP with different ports, where the applications share same custom authentication and authorization library.

Comment: Darn, I need this, too, for a C# scheduler I'm building called Didact.

Comment: Would be nice for solution-wide pre-build event scripts too.