# WinForms Setup project installation executes the previous version

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, versioning, setup-project

After updating WinForms desktop application, **Setup project**  uninstall successfully deletes installation path by C:\Program Files (x86)\myProject, but new, in advance *Clean, Rebuild* and *Build* installation executes the previous version of the code, which was actual at the time of adding Setup project to solution.

What I have to do:

1. In **Configuration manager** from **Build** menu and column check "main Project" and the "Setup project" for both "Debug" and "Release" versions.
2. In **Solution Explorer** my project properties **Application** tab **Assembly Information** change the version of the project for both **Assembly Version** and **File Version** with same versioning values.
3. Change the version in the **Setup project** properties **Version** value with the same version.

I'm not sure if I've missed something to fix issue. Seems like correct way to not change version manually is auto increment of major, minor and patch versioning for Setup project, according this answers [How to have an auto incrementing version number (Visual Studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/826850/8611177) and [Can I automatically increment the file build version when using Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356694/8611177)

but if I'm doing this manually, if there is a 4 digits:

```
Assembly Version: 1, 0, 0, 0
File Version:     1, 0, 0, 0
```

[image]

and  Setup project is a 3:

```
Version: 1, 0, 0
```

[image]

How set properly, if update is:

```
Assembly Version: 1, 0, 0, 1
File Version:     1, 0, 0, 1
```

Or if I should miss 4th digit, what will be correct for **Configuration manager** to avoid previous code  with executable:

```
Assembly Version: 1, 0, 1, 0
File Version:     1, 0, 1, 0
```

and:

```
 Version: 1, 0, 1
```

In my case with this task I found useful following links:

[AssemblyVersionAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) with [AssemblyVersionAttribute(String) Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_AssemblyVersionAttribute__ctor_System_String_) and in addition [What are differences between AssemblyVersion, AssemblyFileVersion and AssemblyInformationalVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65062/8611177) with [The specified version string contains wildcards, which are not compatible with determinism](https://marinovdh.wordpress.com/2018/10/22/68/) and [How to: Specify build events (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the properties of the Setup project, you must also increase the `Version` property. You can do this in the properties window. Then you will be asked whether you want to change the product code. Confirm.

Make sure the file versions of all projects have been incremented.

Then rebuild the setup project.