# How can i upgrade assembly version of files in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have assembly  versions . I am up to 1.0.0.28   I want to update the last number. So can i grab the last number increment and put it as the value.

I have tried

```
$assemblyInfo = Get-Content -Path "c:\AssemblyInfo.cs"        
# Replace last digit of AssemblyFileVersion
$assemblyInfo = $assemblyInfo -replace 
    "^\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(`"([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+`"\)]", 
    ('[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("$1.$2.$3")]')
Write-Host  ($assemblyInfo -match '^\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion')
    
$assemblyInfo | Set-Content -Path "c:\AssemblyInfo.cs" -Encoding UTF8
```

How can i increment the last number ?

Comment: Why not use Visual Studio's built-in feature for [updating the value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826777/503046) on build instead?

Comment: because i am trying to update using jenkins