# Automatically increment the version number in a project's .rc file

Tags: windows, winapi, version, rc

How I can automatically increment the file version in my C/C++ project when I build it?
Currently I have to modify the resources manually before I do the build.
Is there any script or utility to automate this?

Comment: What kind of rc files are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion on the [MSDN Website](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/ccfa1e6a-346c-4296-adf0-2e2164377300) of different approaches to the problem.

Microsoft have also provided [KB237870](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q237870) that explains a (fairly convoluted) method to automate this.

Answer (score -1):

[Can I automatically increment the file build version when using Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio)

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That's for .Net/C#, not for C++ projects which is where the RC files come into play.