# Programmatically uninstalling a program using C#

Tags: c#, uninstallation

Earlier we released an application `<application name>`. Later a new version of the application was released but with different application name `<company name> <application name>`. But both these applications put files in the same program folder. But we have two different versions listed in uninstall programs.

Now that we want to release a newer version. An we want to uninstall the very first version from the user's pc. how can I achieve this using c#. We are using windows 7 64 bit (application is 32 bit and installed in x86 folder).

I don't have the application setup neither the application key

Comment: doesn't a call to `msiexec /u` can do the job ?

Comment: how are these different versions installed? Using msi? Do you know product codes and upgrade codes of the msis?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an installer project you can specify this in the installer properties.

See: [VS2008 Setup Project: Uninstalling the previous MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072856/vs2008-setup-project-uninstalling-the-previous-msi)

Answer (score 1):

If you're application cannot detect it's early version (Different Name) ,than you probably should delete Data from Places where these 2 Application interferes . You could do that with `File.Delete();` but if these Files are somewhere where Application has not permission's you should force it run as Admin by Adding a Manifest File and replace that line.

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the COM WindowsInstaller classes.  You will need to add a reference to the WindowsInstaller class to get access to it.  From here you can browse the MSI and perform actions on it if required.  I use this in my post build to modify the archive to fix a... undocumented functionality of Visual Studio.

```
// Create an Installer instance   
MsiInstaller = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer")) as WindowsInstaller.Installer;
// Open the msi file for Read/Write   
MsiDatabase = MsiInstaller.OpenDatabase(MsiFile.FullName, MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);
```