# MSBUILD: Adding 1 to a variable?

Tags: math, msbuild

I have a text file with a numeric value in it (say 1).
I open and read the file using:

```
<BuildVersionFile Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\BuildNumber.txt"/>
<Target Name="ReadReleaseNotes">
    <ReadLinesFromFile
        File="@(BuildVersionFile)" >
        <Output
          TaskParameter="Lines"
          ItemName="Build
          Version"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
```

I want to increase the value of BuildVersion and write it back to the txt file. How can I do this math?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For MSBuild >= 4.0 you can [perform maths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx#BKMK_PropertyFunctions) against properties.

For MSBuild < 4.0, without writing your own custom task or using an existing addin, I'm not aware of a way of doing this to a plain text file.  If you are stuck with an old version, and wanted to change from a plain text file to AssemblyInfo.cs file, you could use the auto-incrementing feature of `AssemblyVersion` and/or  `AssemblyFileVersion`, replacing a version part with *. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio).