# How do I auto increment the package version number?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I realize that the build/revision number of the assembly can be auto incremented by changing

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

to

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

But how do I auto-increment the version number defined in Package.appxmanifest? That is, the version number accessible through:

```
 Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Version
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I think this question has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio

Comment: @Sajeetharan This is not a duplicate of that question. This question is about WinRT's appx packages.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## **Three liner, versioning by date**

I ran into that issue until I figured out after a lot of research how to achieve automatic versioning in just three line in the `.csproj` file. Here it is:

```
<Target Name="NugetPackAutoVersioning" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="dotnet pack -p:PackageVersion=$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(&quot;yyyy.MM.dd.HHmm&quot;)) --no-build --configuration $(Configuration) --output &quot;$(SolutionDir)nuget&quot;" />
</Target>
```

This will output a NuGet package named like `{ProjectName}.{Year}.{Month}.{Day}.{Hour}{Minute}` in a "nuget" folder at the project root, guaranteeing that packages built later are versioned as posteriors.

Comment: This should be the top answer. Thank you!

Comment: simple and very effective

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! This should be the accepted answer, give this man a beer!

Comment: Any advice on how to do this, not using time, just versioning like 1.0.*

Not using a date?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ask as it wasn't how to version by Date, but build/revision more along the lines of semver.

Comment: Using this might result in a NuGet restore loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786536/visual-studio-2019-restore-completed-nuget-loop. Removing the "ss" part of the version solves this problem

Comment: @HenrikHøyer Great point, I don't know if it would actually apply in this scenario, but better be safe

Comment: Is there a way to use the build number instead of date-time data?

Comment: Beware of using date/time for versioning. It's worth the pains to learn about semantic versioning.

Answer (score 18):

dotnet pack wasn't including runtime/build targets in my package, so I prefer to use the `Generate package on build` package option in the project.

I edited my project file and added the following property inside the `<PropertyGroup>`

```
<PackageVersion>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HHmmss"))</PackageVersion>
```

Comment: What is "dotnet pack"? The literal command line `dotnet pack`? Or something else?

Comment: Yep the command line dotnet pack -- wasn't correctly setting the package version in my resulting package.

Comment: Works perfectly in VS2019 on .NET Core 5, Thanks!

Comment: You're missing the `<` when closing PackageVersion. It threw me off for a minute.

Comment: Using this might result in a NuGet restore loop. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786536/visual-studio-2019-restore-completed-nuget-loop. Removing the "ss" part of the version solves this problem

Answer (score 13):

In your `.csproj` file, you should add a property named `AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision` with the value set to `True`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>

    ...

    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>

    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This will auto-increment the appx package version every time you build it through Visual Studio.

Comment: tried this, didn't work for me. (added the <import> and the <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>).  Package number remains the same

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2017, I created a PowerShell script to pull the package id and version number information by looking in a few places and update the .csproj file if needed.

The help comment in the file describes how to call it from your .csproj during a build (and build the NuGet package as part of the build):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS

Update version information in the .csproj file in preparation for building a nuget
package.
.DESCRIPTION

Discovers the package name and latest version. If that package exists and is newer
than the target that goes into it, do nothing; otherwise, increment the version
information in the .csproj file (without updating that .csproj file last modified
time).

The latest version gets picked from the maximum of the package/file/assembly
versions in the .csproj file and the version found on the nuget server.
.PARAMETER csproj

The path to the .csproj file to check
.PARAMETER target

The path to the build target (the DLL) that goes into the package. Used to decide whether to
increment the version or not.
.PARAMETER packageDir

The location packages end up.
.PARAMETER nugetSite

The domain name or IP address of the nuget server to query for package version information.
.EXAMPLE

To build a nuget package on every build, add this to the csproj file:

    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <Target Name="PostcompileScript" AfterTargets="Build">
       <Exec Command="powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -noexit -file &quot;$(SolutionDir)UpdateCsprojPackageVersion.ps1&quot; -csproj &quot;$(ProjectPath)&quot; -target &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; -packageDir &quot;$(SolutionDir)nuget&quot;" />
       <Exec Command="dotnet pack --no-build --include-symbols --include-source --configuration $(Configuration) --output &quot;$(SolutionDir)nuget" />
     </Target>
    </Project>
#>
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$csproj,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$target,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$packageDir,
    [string]$nugetSite = "local-nuget-server"
)


$csproj = $csproj.Trim()

Write-Output "Increment package/file/assembly version in $csproj"

function ParseVersion($version)
{
    $major = 0
    $minor = 1
    $build = 0
    $revisionType = 'alpha'
    $revision = 0
    $gotData = $false
    $m = [regex]::Match($version, '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:-([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)|\.(\d+))?')
    if ($m.Success)
    {
        $major = $m.Groups[1].Value -as [int]
        $minor = $m.Groups[2].Value -as [int]
        $build = $m.Groups[3].Value -as [int]
        if ($m.Groups[4].Success)
        {
            $revisionType = $m.Groups[4].Value.ToLower()
            $revision = $m.Groups[5].Value -as [int]
        }
        else
        {
            $revisionType = ''
            if ($m.Groups[6].Success)
            {
                $revision = $m.Groups[6].Value
            }
        }
    }

    return [Convert]::ToInt32($major, 10), [Convert]::ToInt32($minor, 10), [Convert]::ToInt32($build, 10), $revisionType, [Convert]::ToInt32($revision, 10)
}

function VersionGreaterOrEqual($major1, $minor1, $build1, $revision1, $major2, $minor2, $build2, $revision2)
{
    return ($major1 -gt $major2 -or ($major1 -eq $major2 -and ($minor1 -gt $minor2 -or ($minor1 -eq $minor2 -and ($build1 -gt $build2 -or ($build1 -eq $build2 -and $revision1 -ge $revision2))))))
}

# Read csproj (XML)
$xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$xml.Load($csproj)
$project = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project")
if ($project -eq $null)
{
    $project = $xml.CreateElement("Project")
    $xml.AppendChild($project)
}
$propertyGroup = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]")
if ($propertyGroup -eq $null)
{
    $propertyGroup = $project.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("PropertyGroup"))
}

# Look for the package identifier in various places in the project file, as a last resort, use the project file name.
$packageId = $null
$packageidFrom = "PackageId in csproj"
$packageIdNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]/PackageId")
if ($packageIdNode -ne $null)
{
    $packageId = $packageIdNode.'#text'
}

if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($packageId))
{
    $assemblyTitle = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]/AssemblyTitle")
    if ($assemblyTitle -ne $null)
    {
        $packageId = $assemblyTitle.'#text'
        $packageidFrom = "AssemblyTitle in csproj"
    }

    if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($packageId))
    {
        $assemblyName = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]/AssemblyName")
        if ($assemblyName -ne $null)
        {
            $packageId = $assemblyName.'#text'
            $packageidFrom = "AssemblyName in csproj"
        }

        if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($packageId))
        {
            $title = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]/Title")
            if ($title -ne $null)
            {
                $packageId = $title.'#text'
                $packageidFrom = "Title in csproj"
            }


            if ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($packageId))
            {
                $packageId = (New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($csproj)).BaseName
                $packageidFrom = "file name of csproj"
                if ($title -eq $null)
                {
                    $title = $propertyGroup.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("Title"))
                }

                $title.'#text' = $packageId
            }

            if ($assemblyName -eq $null)
            {
                $assemblyName = $propertyGroup.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("AssemblyName"))
            }

            $assemblyName.'#text' = $packageId
        }

        if ($assemblyTitle -eq $null)
        {
            $assemblyTitle = $propertyGroup.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("AssemblyTitle"))
        }

        $assemblyTitle.'#text' = $packageId
    }

    if ($packageIdNode -eq $null)
    {
        $packageIdNode = $propertyGroup.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("PackageId"))
    }

    $packageIdNode.'#text' = $packageId;
}

Write-Output "    Found Package Identifier ""$packageId"" from $packageIdFrom"

# Get the latest version from the nuget server.
# The query comes from running nuget.exe with the -Verbose option (and guessing that the search term can be a regular expression).
# The response comes back as XML
$nugetXml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$nugetXml.Load("http://$nugetSite/api/v2/Search()?`$filter=IsAbsoluteLatestVersion&searchTerm=%27^$packageId$%27&targetFramework=%27%27&includePrerelease=true")
$nugetVersionNode = $nugetXml.SelectSingleNode("feed.entry.properties.Version")
$nugetVersion = ''
if ($nugetVersionNode -ne $null)
{
    $nugetVersion = $nugetVersionNode.'#text'
}

# Retrieve Version Nodes
$packageVersionNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]/PackageVersion")
if ($packageVersionNode -eq $null) {
    $packageVersionNode = $propertyGroup.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("PackageVersion"))
}
$assemblyVersionNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]/AssemblyVersion")
if ($assemblyVersionNode -eq $null) {
    $assemblyVersionNode = $propertyGroup.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("AssemblyVersion"))
}
$fileVersionNode = $xml.SelectSingleNode("/Project/PropertyGroup[not(@*)]/FileVersion")
if ($fileVersionNode -eq $null) {
    $fileVersionNode = $propertyGroup.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement("FileVersion"))
}

$packageVersion = $packageVersionNode.'#text'
$assemblyVersion = $assemblyVersionNode.'#text'
$fileVersion = $fileVersionNode.'#text'

Write-Output "    Read versions: qat-nuget=""$nugetVersion"", package=""$packageVersion"", file=""$fileVersion"", assembly=""$assemblyVersion"""

# Split the Version Numbers
$major, $minor, $build, $revisionType, $revision = ParseVersion $nugetVersion
$paMajor, $paMinor, $paBuild, $paRevisionType, $paRevision = ParseVersion $packageVersion
$avMajor, $avMinor, $avBuild, $avRevisionType, $avRevision = ParseVersion $assemblyVersion
$fvMajor, $fvMinor, $fvBuild, $fvRevisionType, $fvRevision = ParseVersion $fileVersion

# choose between qat-nuget's package version and the package version found in the project file
if ((VersionGreaterOrEqual $paMajor $paMinor $paBuild 0 $major $minor $build 0) -and (($paRevisionType -eq '' -or $paRevisionType -gt $revisionType) -or ($paRevisionType -eq $revisionType -and $paRevision -gt $revision)))
{
    $major = $paMajor
    $minor = $paMinor
    $build = $paBuild
    $revisionType = $paRevisionType
    $revision = $paRevision
}

# Because of the way the build works, the file and assembly versions being set are for the
# _next_ build, the package version is for the _current_ build. We err on the side of the
# package version - that is, the file and assembly version may not increment at edge cases.
# If you want to be sure that all the versions are the same in a package, you must build
# twice.

# To keep revisions for file and assembly alpha/beta/rc/release builds going in order, we
# give the different releaseType values different base revision values.
switch($revisionType.ToLower())
{
   "rc" { $revisionDelta = 20001 }
   "beta" { $revisionDelta = 10001 }
   "alpha" { $revisionDelta = 1 }
   default { $revisionDelta = 40001 }  # for release revisions
}

# Boost the version to the assembly version or the file version value if those are greater
if ((VersionGreaterOrEqual $avMajor $avMinor $avBuild $avRevision $major $minor $build ($revision + $revisionDelta)) -and (VersionGreaterOrEqual $avMajor $avMinor $avBuild $avRevision $fvMajor $fvMinor $fvBuild $fvRevision))
{
    $major = $avMajor
    $minor = $avMinor
    $build = $avBuild
    $revision = $avRevision - $revisionDelta
}
elseif (VersionGreaterOrEqual $fvMajor $fvMinor $fvBuild $fvRevision $major $minor $build ($revision + $revisionDelta))
{
    $major = $fvMajor
    $minor = $fvMinor
    $build = $fvBuild
    $revision = $fvRevision - $revisionDelta
}

if ($revision -lt 0)
{
    $revision -eq 0
}

$fileAssemblyRevision = $revision + $revisionDelta
$fileAssemblyBuild = $build


if ($revisionType -ne "")
{
    $oldPackageName = "$packageId.$major.$minor.$build-$revisionType$revision.nupkg"
}
else
{
    $oldPackageName = "$packageId.$major.$minor.$build.nupkg"
}

$oldPackage = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($packageDir, $oldPackageName)

if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($oldPackage) -and [System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($oldPackage) -ge [System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($target))
{
    $targetName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($target)
    Write-Output "    * Not incrementing version - $oldPackageName newer than $targetName"
}
else
{
    # Increment revision or build
    if ($revisionType -ne "")
    {
        $fileAssemblyRevision = $fileAssemblyRevision + 1
        $revision = $revision + 1
    }
    else
    {
        $fileAssemblyBuild = $fileAssemblyBuild + 1
        $build = $build + 1
        $fileAssemblyRevision = 0
        $revision = $revision + 0
    }


    # Put the incremented version into the csproj file and save it
    $fileAssemblyVersion = "$major.$minor.$fileAssemblyBuild.$fileAssemblyRevision"
    $assemblyVersionNode.RemoveAll()
    $dummy = $assemblyVersionNode.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($fileAssemblyVersion))
    $fileVersionNode.RemoveAll()
    $dummy = $fileVersionNode.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($fileAssemblyVersion))
    $packageVersionNode.RemoveAll()
    if ($revisionType -eq '')
    {
        $packageVersion = "$major.$minor.$build"
    }
    else
    {
        $packageVersion = "$major.$minor.$build-$revisionType$revision"
    }

    $dummy = $packageVersionNode.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode($packageVersion))

    Write-Output "    Set file/assembly version to $fileAssemblyVersion, package version to $packageVersion"

    $lastWriteTime = [System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime($csproj)
    $xml.Save($csproj)
    [System.IO.File]::SetLastWriteTime($csproj, $lastWriteTime)
}
```

This scripts enforces the questionable practice of keeping the file/assembly/package version numbers in sync - we have found that practice useful. To accomplish this, revision numbers need special handling. A delta is given for beta, release candidate, and release so version numbers don't decrease when moving from package alpha → beta, etc.

There is a trick in there because the writing of the project file comes after the build. This means the file and assembly version numbers must be kept one increment behind the package version number (the package gets built after the increment).

This script assumes you have a NuGet server to query. It shouldn't be hard to chop that code out if you don't have one.

Comment: What is the meaning of the assignment `$assemblyTitle.'#text' = $packageId`? What does the `.'#text'` part do?

Comment: a bit later.. @PeterMortensen : In powershell xml accessor, the textproperty of an element is #text. In order for the powershell interpreter to parse a property of an object with a special character, the property is enclosed in single quotes. Thus, .'#text' accesses the text (raw text between the tags) property of the $assemblyTitle xmlElement.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create a package there is an option for this functionality, and here is a screenshot for that. All you have to do is check the Automatically increment option.

From Visual Studio, navigate like menu *Project* → *Store* → *Create App Packages* → *Automatically increment*

[image]

Comment: No "Project => Store" in my visual studio and nohting about "Create App Package" that I can see.