# update automatically constant value in code on each build in C# / Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, build-process

I would like to have a constant whose value would be updated automatically each time a project is built with the current date time.  Is this possible?

For example, I would have a constant:

```
string LastBuildDate = "01/07/2014 19:20 PM"
```

Then, if I build 15 minutes later, this would automatically be updated to:

```
string LastBuildDate = "01/07/2014 19:35 PM"
```

It doesn't have to be specifically such a constant.  I would like to be able to know when the application was last compiled and show it in the administration area of a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the same functionality I was looking for can be done by setting the version in `AssemblyInfo.cs` to `1.0.*`, as per below.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Then, I added the below code:

```
    public static DateTimeOffset GetLastApplicationBuildDateFromAssembly()
    {

        int gmtOfBuild = 1; //as the date/time is of the local machine where it was built, in my case +1 gmt

        var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var executingAssemblyName = executingAssembly.GetName();
        var version = executingAssemblyName.Version;
        DateTimeOffset relativeDate = new DateTimeOffset(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(gmtOfBuild , 0, 0));

        int daysAfter1stJan2000 = version.Build;
        int secondsdAfterMidnight = version.MinorRevision * 2;

        var buildDate = relativeDate.AddDays(daysAfter1stJan2000).AddSeconds(secondsdAfterMidnight);
        return buildDate;

    }
```

Reference: [Can I automatically increment the file build version when using Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I use a plugin for Visual Studio called [Build Version Increment](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/) and I set it to do Year/month day for my version so Every time I compile it updates the AssemblyInfo.cs, then I just use this code snippet to display the version in a console and usually in the header of all my apps. I have to keep multiple pieces of software installed and updated on 400 machines so its nice to easily know who has what version:

code snippet:

```
Version vs = new Version(Application.ProductVersion);
string _myVersion = vs.Major + "." + vs.Minor + "." + vs.Build + "." + vs.Revision;
```

Hope this helps,
C5

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using T4 template.

Insert the following code into your project file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

And create .tt file like the following:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static string LastBuildDate = "<#=DateTime.Now#>";
    }
}
```

It will create the .cs file with content like, for example

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static string LastBuildDate = "07/02/2014 10:34:46";
    }
}
```

Note: the path to the text template targets file may differ depending on installed visual studio version.
Also, you should insert "<Import Project ..." line after the line that imports "Microsoft.CSharp.targets"; otherwise it will not work.