# How to auto increase the build number in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, build, numbers

I am using Visual C++ 2008. I want to find a way to auto increase the build number each time I rebuild the project.

I find the following article: [Can I automatically increment the file build version when using Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio)

But I cannot find "AssemblyInfo.cs" file at all, so the solution in the article does not work.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The article is about C# project but I guess yours is for C++. What about using **DATE** macro? [Predefined Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)