# How do I automatically increase assembly version number in .NET Standard Class Library Project

Tags: visual-studio, versioning, assemblyinfo, .net-standard, assemblyversionattribute

This Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio) has many answer for automatically increase the assembly version number in Visual Studio project.

But when comes to [.NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) class library project it doesn't has a AssemblyInfo.cs file.

[image]

So how can I increase the assembly version number in .NET Standard Project?

Comment: The `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` can go into any file - what happens if you just put it at the top of one of your normal .cs files?

Comment: @WaiHaLee I tried your suggestion. Getting syntext error: "Duplicate AssemblyVersion attribute". I did a text search, but no files has AssemblyVersion decorated.

Comment: @Rahul the assembly attribute is generated in the obj folder, build the project and click the error will take you to that file. I think the current version of compiler does not recognise the technique of wild card yet.

Comment: VS2017 solves a problem that, I think, nobody ever once realized they had.  Some odds that they'll remove it again as long as enough programmers complain about it.  Still, [AssemblyVersion] is a very big deal and auto-incrementing it is a very bad idea.  Just use Help > Send Feedback > Provide a Suggestion, post the link here and when enough SO users agree then you'll be happier.

Comment: @HansPassant I have created a community request as you suggested:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/50409/increase-assembly-version-number-in-net-standard-c.html

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017, the version of the assembly can be set in project properties -> Package tab, but there is no way to automatically increment the version number at each build, have to set it manually.