# ClickOnce: How to Dynamically Detect Data Directory Between Debug, Release, and Publish

Tags: vb.net, debugging, clickonce, publish, data-files

I'm trying to find a vb.net method that returns the path to the directory where project files labelled as 'Data Files' are stored: which is valid for ClickOnce applications during development and after the app has been Published?

I've found '[ClickOnce: How to Dynamically Detect Data Directory Between Debug, Release, and Publish](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winformsue/2006/04/26/clickonce-how-to-dynamically-detect-data-directory-between-debug-release-and-publish/)' dated 2006. It doesn't feel right. Surly Microsoft will have provided a more elegant solution during the past 11 years.

Thanks for your help,

Tod.

Comment: `Surly Microsoft will have provided a more elegant solution during the past 11 years` - I wouldn't get my hopes up. To me ClickOnce has always been a mess and I don't get why people (still) use it. :)

Comment: Thanks Vincent - for me it's because I know no better! I've fired up Visual Studio and it kinda leads you towards ClickOnce. As an amateur, the automatic versioning/updating mechanism is useful. What other methods could I use?

Comment: There's the regular [**Setup Project**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) which lets you create an MSI installer. As for automatic versioning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/356694 (the post mentions VS 2008, but this works in any Visual Studio version)