# How to assign version to dll's or exe's in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created one C# project. Output of that project is dll. I have updated everything in AssemblyInfo.cs file like Company, product, copyright. I want to assign version to that dll in devops pipeline.

I have created Azure Devops pipeline CI/CD for that project.

I want to assign NuGet package version as dll version.

Is it possible to assign NuGet verison as dll's version which are going to be delivered in Release Pipeline? If yes, Please help me by providing some info or steps for that.

Comment: Which nuget? do you pack it with nuget?

Comment: Confirm your issue is that you want use the dll`s version as nuget package version? But your title confuses me, which you want is assign version to dll's or exe's. So, I need to confirm this with you.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes I pack with nuget

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I'm assigning one verion to dll in AssemblyInfo.cs. Let say that version as 1.2.0. Lets say my nuget  package name as MyTestNugetPackage.

After Nuget pack command I want my package should be MyTestNugetPackage.1.2.0

Comment: Or Can we automate assigning version to dll

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to assign NuGet verison as dll's version which are going to be delivered in Release Pipeline?

As I answered in [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084052/net-analyzer-package-version-vs-assembly-version):

> NuGet doesn’t use either of these. **It uses a third versioning
>   attribute: AssemblyInformationalVersion** - the Product version of the
>   assembly

But this versioning attribute was removed in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, because they don’t apply to semantic versioning.

To assign NuGet verison as dll's version, we just need add a assembly `AssemblyInformationalVersion` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.2.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.2.0")]
```

Then use the `nuget pack "ProjectName.csproj"` command line or nuget pack task in the pipeline to create the nuget package, the generate nuget package with version `1.0.2` as the file version as dll version.

Hope this helps.