# What can I use to automate incrementing a version number?

Tags: versioning

I have a .txt file called "service-config" that looks like the below:

```
ServiceName=my-service  
ServiceVersion=2.0.4  
ToolsAccountNumber=3219684321  
SharedAccountNumber=6843219687  
NumberOfEcsTasks=2
```

I need a way to automatically increment the service version by 0.0.1 so when I run this solution the version will go to 2.0.5.
What would be the best way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Which IDE are you working on?

Comment: Also, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio if you're on Visual Studio

Comment: I am using Intellij