# Increment Nuget package version on publish or release build

Tags: c#, versioning, nuget-package

I am wondering if there is a way to make my project increment the nuget package version everytime I publish/build it? I tried adding the `AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision` property to my csproj file but it didn't seem to help. If this is not possible, maybe it is possible to increase the version everytime I do a release build?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net47</TargetFrameworks>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Found this for example: [Can I automatically increment the file build version when using Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356543/can-i-automatically-increment-the-file-build-version-when-using-visual-studio?rq=1)
But its for Visual Studio 2008.