# How do I get the current published version in a .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to display the current version of a .NET application that I have deployed using the publish wizard. There is a nice option to automatically update the version number every time I publish my application.

I found another question (*[Automatically update version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650/automatically-update-version-number)*) that had this to get the current version:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

This gets you the version you set in the project properties, but not the version that is automatically incremented each time you publish.

Comment: Can you qualify that assertion somehow? GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version works just fine on release assemblies

Comment: Maybe I meant publish and not deploy. I can go change that in the question. When I run through the publish wizard it automatically updates a publish version. In code it is referred to as the Deployed version.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I ended up using this little bit of code to get the current deployed version or if it isn't deployed the current assembly version.

```
private Version GetRunningVersion()
{
  try
  {
    return Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
  }
  catch
  {
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
  }
}
```

I had to add references to `System.Deployment` and `System.Reflection`.

Comment: You don't have to use that hackish try/catch block. You can check to see if your app is deployed `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed`

Comment: `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` throws an exception if it is not running as a ClickOnce application and the result may be closing the entire application. You do want the try-catch - otherwise you are doing a disservice to current and/or future users.

Comment: After adding ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed, I never saw an exception again. It was only when accessing the CurrentDeployment class.

Answer (score 52):

You can use the following test

```
if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) {
    return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
}
```

to avoid the exception (as detailed in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e01c2163-41a0-4bc0-80b8-79ae79db2bbb/)).

Also, I don't think you can get the current publish version via Visual Studio debugging because accessing `CurrentDeployment` will throw an `InvalidDeploymentException`.

Comment: I prefer this method over the accepted answer.  The accepted answer makes no distinction about which exception it's handling.  It's generally bad practice to make sweeping exception handlers.

Comment: Likewise. It also doesn't revert arbitrarily to the assembly version; it's not comparable to the deployment version, so it shouldn't be used as a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

I used following solution for this problem, and it is working for me:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "MyProd.application"));
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if (ds.Tables.Count > 1) {
    dt = ds.Tables[1];
    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["version"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Upvote because it is simple and a light operation, whereas, even MS doesn't provide a good way to access this.

Answer (score 2):

Based in the answer from **Jason**, I ended up with this:

Add Reference to System.Deployment.

```
string versionDeploy = Application.ProductVersion;              
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    this.lblVersion.Caption = string.Format("Versión {0} DESA", versionDeploy);
}
else
{
    if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        Version Deploy = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
        versionDeploy = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", Deploy.Major, Deploy.Minor, Deploy.Build, Deploy.Revision);
    }
    this.lblVersion.Caption = string.Format("Versión {0} PROD", versionDeploy);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Deployment.Application;
```

and

```
string yourPublishedVersionNumber=ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()
```

Comment: Worth checking for `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` for when you run it locally, as otherwise the `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment` throws an exception

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Configuration
Public Function GetAppVersion() As String
    Dim ass As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim ver As System.Version = ass.GetName().Version
    Return ver.Major & "." & ver.Minor & "." & ver.Revision
End Function
```

Comment: Not only is it the question, but it is important to note that this grabs the application version NOT the publication version. I have it set to auto-increment on an Excel AddIn, so every publish comes out 1.0.0.138 or something similar while the above code returns 1.0.0.0 which is set under the properties tab.