# Winforms: getting Publish Version number?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, system.reflection

I've got a Winforms app and want to display the version number so that we can know if our update scripts are running correctly. Is there a way to get the Publish Version number (as displayed in the Property Pages of the app, Publish tab)?

When I use Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version etc it seems to use the AssemblyVersion number from AssemblyInfo.vb, which isn't the same.

If I use wildcards in the AssemblyInfo.vb it comes out different numbers again.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248824/how-do-i-get-the-current-published-version-in-a-net-application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should get you the publish version:

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
```

Comment: For reference: [the msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentversion.aspx)

Comment: you need to include System.Deployment.Application

Answer (score 3):

> Try this one:
>
> ```
> If  My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed Then
>    Label1.Text = My.Application.Deployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()
> End If
> ```
>
> The publish version will appear in runtime.

I didn't catch the "publish version will appear in runtime" to start with but I was able to use this and set my label to say "N/A during debug " then when published it changes and displays the published version.

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me Isidoros, with the following ToString modification.

```
Imports System.Deployment.Application

If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
    strTemp = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString
Else
    strTemp = Application.ProductVersion.ToString
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
If  My.Application.IsNetworkDeployed Then
    Label1.Text = My.Application.Deployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()
End If
```

The publish version will appear in runtime.

Comment: This worked for me! The value is only available AFTER it is published.

Answer (score 1):

If application is not published you will get an error or you are in development mode you will get an error. Try the below:

```
Imports System.Deployment.Application

If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
   lblVersion.Text = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
Else
   lblVersion.Text = Application.ProductVersion
End If
```