# Get Publish version number for ClickOnce app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Building a Visual Basic ClickOnce application. I want to display the Publish version number. When I display My.Application.Info.Version.ToString, it always reports 1.0.0.0. The publish version is actually 1.0.0.30. How can I pull the correct Publish version? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [Winforms: getting Publish Version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423729/winforms-getting-publish-version-number)

There's a bug in the answer, though. The correct code is:

```
Imports System.Deployment.Application

If ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed Then
    strTemp = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString
Else
    strTemp = Application.ProductVersion.ToString
End If
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's how it is intended to work, the published version will appear at runtime.

Comment: Hi Codexer. Please note the addition of ".ToString" --the routine won't work without it (at least, that's the behavior I saw in my app).