# Is there something like Rust's std::option_env in csharp?

Tags: c#, rust

In Rust you can [inspect environment variables at compile time](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env.html) like so:

```
let sha: Option<&'static str> = option_env!("CI_COMMIT_SHA");
println!("CI_COMMIT_SHA: {:?}", sha);
```

Is this possible now C# too, or [do I really have to `sed`-replace the source file during the build process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4450231/303290) like back in the old days?

Is there a convenient way to evaluate environment variables during compile time in netcore/.NET5/C#9 or later nowadays?

Comment: Look into source generators for Roslyn.