# Application.ProductVersion is not working

Tags: c#

`Application.ProductVersion` is not showing the incremental version. can anybody help me how to perform this, using C# ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have build and revision incremented for you but not major and minor.

Simply substitute

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

with

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

in the AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: yes i add up the initial values in assembly that is 1.0.0.0 but it is not increment in each build. i am showing the Version detail in my app "About Tab" via using code like this label.Text = Application.ProductName + " Version " + Application.ProductVersion

Comment: @Asad the value should not be 1.0.0.0 but 1.0.* if you wish the build/revision part to be incremented automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried grabbing the Assembly's version?

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Also check out this other SO post - I think this is what you are looking for.

[Automatically update version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650/automatically-update-version-number)

Below is a second link to a .Net add-in that automatically increments the:

- Major
- Minor
- Build
- Revision

http://testdox.wordpress.com/versionupdater/

Comment: yes i add up the initial values in assembly that is 1.0.0.0 but it is not increment in each build. i am showing the Version detail in my app "About Tab" via using code like this label.Text = Application.ProductName + " Version " + Application.ProductVersion

Comment: @AsadIqbal I edited my post with a link. I think this should get you rolling.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it works well to simply display the date of the last build using the following wherever a product version is needed:

```
System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd.HHMM")
```

Rather than attempting to get the version from something like the following:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false);
object attribute = null;

if (attributes.Length > 0)
{
    attribute = attributes[0] as System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;
}
```