# c# assign version number via Environment Variable

Tags: c#, environment-variables, version-numbering

I currently have a `VersionInfo.cs` file that contains the following.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Version
//      Revision
//
//You can specify all the values or you can defaul the Revision and Build Numbers
//by using the '*' as shown below:
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

This file is added as a link to all the projects in my solution, so updating the version number in one, updates all of it. This works fine.

But I'm wondering is it possible to retrieve version number from an environment variable and then use that in the `VersionInfo.cs` file?. Can this be done in the `VersionInfo.cs` file itself?.

I searched for something like this and so far got nothing.

Comment: There is another topic about this. It may be help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650/automatically-update-version-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PowerShell script that updates `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyFileVersion` based on a environment variable called `BUILD_NUMBER`.

```powershell
if (Test-Path env:BUILD_NUMBER) {
    Write-Host "Updating AssemblyVersion to $env:BUILD_NUMBER"

    # Get the AssemblyInfo.cs
    $assemblyInfo = Get-Content -Path .\MyShinyApplication\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs

    # Replace last digit of AssemblyVersion
    $assemblyInfo = $assemblyInfo -replace 
        "^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(`"([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+`"\)]", 
        ('[assembly: AssemblyVersion("$1.$2.$3.' + $env:BUILD_NUMBER + '")]')
    Write-Host  ($assemblyInfo -match '^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion')
        
    # Replace last digit of AssemblyFileVersion
    $assemblyInfo = $assemblyInfo -replace 
        "^\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(`"([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+`"\)]", 
        ('[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("$1.$2.$3.' + $env:BUILD_NUMBER + '")]')
    Write-Host  ($assemblyInfo -match '^\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion')
        
    $assemblyInfo | Set-Content -Path .\MyShinyApplication\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs -Encoding UTF8
} else {
    Write-Warning "BUILD_NUMBER is not set."
}
```

Call this script from a pre-build step on your build system.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is not possible to do it inside `VersionInfo.cs` itself. Even though it is possible to pass special symbols to C# compiler (see also [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) about this), they cannot hold a value, unlike C/C++ symbols.

However, it is certainly possible to generate `VersionInfo.cs` algorithmically with, for example, another simple C# program. Firstly, write a program that modifies `VersionInfo.cs` with information obtained from another source, probably from `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` method invocation. Then add a **pre-build** command to the build of your project, see an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) for details on how to do it. At **pre-build** event, call your program so that it will update `VersionInfo.cs` before the compiler is invoked.